# Azure CLI Equivalent to Powershell's Add-MsolRoleMember

Tags: python, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am using [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) and am trying to find a command equivalent to the following Powershell command:

```
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectID $roleID -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $appObjectId
```

I am using this command to add an Azure AD Application Principal to the **"User Account Administrator"** role.

I used this link to install the [MSOL Powershell libraries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975125.aspx) which includes the "Add-MsolRoleMember" command.

Because I need commands that run on Mac, Linux, etc., I am trying to use the latest version of the "Azure CLI", although I'm open to other code samples (e.g. Python).

Below are the cli commands I have tried so far:

```
az login --tenant <my tenant id>
# I get my app id from this:
az ad app list
# I cannot get the following to work, and suspect I am running 
# the incorrect command
az role assignment create --assignee <my app id>  --role <role id>
```

So my questions is: How can I add a role to an app principal using CLI or some other library that runs on Mac, Linux, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is **no** library work on Linux that we can add member to Azure organizational role.

For now, we can use Azure CLI 2.0 to manager Azure AD **user**, **app**, **group**, and **service principals**, but we **can't** use CLI 2.0 to add member to azure organizational role.

```
az role assignment create --assignee <my app id>  --role <role id>
```

This command `az role assignment` used to manager resource group roles. For example, we want to grant user **Owner** permission. we can find this role via Azure portal in this screenshoot:
[image]

About organizational role, we can find them in this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles-azure-portal), like **Billing Administrator**, **Compliance Administrator**. Different with resource group permission.

You could give your feedback to this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback), all of the feedback you share in this link will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams.

============
Update:
[image]

Comment: I have multiple Azure AD instances and multiple Resource Groups.  I cannot find the "User Account Administrator" in the IAM section of any of my resource groups.  Could you please provide instructions?   I have also tried the "Directory Role" section under Azure AD, but this does not show the "User Account Administrator" as shown in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal#assign-a-role-to-a-user

Comment: @GregThatcher sorry, I did not describe clearly, I mean there are two roles, one is Directory Role, another is Resource Groups Role, there are different, for now we can use CLI 2.0 to set Resource Group Role. For now,`User account Administrator` have changed, new name is `User administrator`. I will add this screenshot to my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks @JasonYeMsft, but I believe that screenshot is for adding a role to a normal user.  I need to add this role to the Application Principal (a.k.a. "Service Principal") associated with an "App Registration" in one of my Azure AD instances.  The new Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember  and Get-AzureADDirectoryRole Powershell commands looks promising (and possibly cross-platform), but I have not been able to get these to work.

Comment: According to your description, maybe you are looking for this command, `Get-AzureADApplication` and  `Set-AzureADApplication -AppRoles`, more information about application role, please refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest

Comment: @GregThatcher Have you try this command `set-AzureADapplication -Approles` ?

Comment: @GregThatcher Did you find the answer to this question, if yes, could you please post your detailed solution to this issue as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.  By the way, please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @JasonYeMsft I'm going to try to get the set-azureADApplication to work on Linux's Powershell this week.  If there are any special instructions to get this to work on Linux, please let me know.  I could also use a similar (non-Msol) PowerShell command to get the User Account Administrator role id.  Alternatively, if there is a way to make the MSOL commands work on Linux, that would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A good article how to do this can be found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/08/29/how-to-add-an-azure-ad-role-to-a-enterprise-application-service-principal/

And the code looks as follows:

```
# Fetch User Account Administrator role instance
$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'User Account Administrator'}

# If role instance does not exist, instantiate it based on the role template
if ($role -eq $null) {
    # Instantiate an instance of the role template
    $roleTemplate = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'User Account Administrator'}
    Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId $roleTemplate.ObjectId

    # Fetch User Account Administrator role instance again
    $role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'User Account Administrator'}
}

#Now that we have the object IDs for the AAD role, we will need to get both object IDs to add the role to the enterprise application. We can use the command below :
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId -RefObjectId $BeckeChB2Cs0v1GraphApiAdSPN.ObjectId
```

Comment: The request is to provide Azure CLI equivalent so that it could be done on Linux/macOS and not PowerShell code which can only run on Windows. And you provide PowerShell code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be done with the `Update-MgRoleManagementDirectoyRoleAssignment` command in the `Microsoft.Graph` module works on Powershell 7, which is cross-platform.

From Powershell 7:

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph
```

Then:

```
Connect-Graph <follow instructions to authenticate your commands>
Update-MgRoleManagementDirectoyRoleAssignment -PrincipalID <your service princiapl> -RoleDefinitionID <Role Definition>
```

Documentation for the Microsoft.Graph.Identity modules seems sparse/non-existent, but you can look at the Microsoft Graph API description here for guidance:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-assign-graph